# how to convert part of a String or CharSequence to uppercase?

Tags: java, string, uppercase

Is there a way to convert part of a String (or a CharSequence to uppercase?

Ideally, a method that produces the following behavior.

```
String hello = "hello";
System.out.println(hello.toUpperCase(0,3);
//Output: HEL
```

I am aware of toUpperCase() but i only want to capitalise part of the string.

Comment: Very simple to write such a function yourself.

Comment: Look into `substring`

Comment: Just combine `substring()` and `toUpperCase()`

Comment: substring! great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with two calls - [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) to get the sequence you're interested in and then [`toUpperCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase--) to capitalize it:

```
System.out.println(hello.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

use `substring()` to get part of string and then change it's case

```
 String hello = "hello";
 String temp  = hello.subString(0,3).toUpperCase();
 temp += hello.subString(3);
 System.out.println(temp);  //  HELlo
```